# Using a cursor with pg-promise

Tags: javascript, pg-promise, database-cursor

I'm struggling to find an example of using a cursor with pg-promise.  node-postgres supports its pg-cursor extension.  Is there a way to use that extension with pg-promise?  I'm attempting to implement an asynchronous generator (to support for-await-of).  pg-query-stream doesn't seem to be appropriate for this use case (I need "pull", rather than "push").

As an example, I use SQLite for my unit tests and my (abridged) generator looks something like this...

```
async function* () {

    const stmt = await db.prepare(...);

    try {

        while (true) {

            const record = await stmt.get();

            if (isUndefined(record)) {

                break;
            }

            yield value;
        }
    }
    finally {

        stmt.finalize();
    }
}
```

Using pg-cursor, the assignment to `stmt` would become something like `client.query(new Cursor(...))`, `stmt.get` would become `stmt.read(1)` and `stmt.finalize` would become `stmt.close`.

Thanks

Comment: Cursor examples for the base driver are [here](https://node-postgres.com/api/cursor), so you just have to use manual [connect](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#connect) to access  `Client` and use it in the same way as in the examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [the original examples](https://node-postgres.com/api/cursor), we can modify them for use with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```
const pgp = require('pg-promise')(/* initialization options */);
const db = pgp(/* connection details */);

const Cursor = require('pg-cursor');

const c = await db.connect(); // manually managed connection

const text = 'SELECT * FROM my_large_table WHERE something > $1';
const values = [10];

const cursor = c.client.query(new Cursor(text, values));

cursor.read(100, (err, rows) => {
  cursor.close(() => {
    c.done(); // releasing connection
  });
  // or you can just do: cursor.close(c.done);
});
```

Since [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) doesn't support [pg-cursor](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-cursor) explicitly, one has to manually acquire the connection object and use it directly, as shown in the example above.

> pg-query-stream doesn't seem to be appropriate for this use case (I need `pull`, rather than `push`).

Actually, in the context of these libraries, both streams and cursors are only for pulling data. So it would be ok for you to use streaming also.

**UPDATE**

For reading data in a simple and safe way, check out [pg-iterator](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-iterator).